# Relationship Extended Report produces errors

Tags: wordpress, extension, civireport

I have been getting errors when trying to run relationship report extension & from some reports from this template created in 12/14. We depend on these reports for much of our work.

Can anyone help?
Thanks,

**First error:**  the extended report template has no way to save or run the report.

---

**Second error:** when running previously successful reports I get the following error:

```
contact_a_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 232

Notice: Undefined index: contact_b_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 233

Notice: Undefined index: contact_a_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 103

Notice: Undefined index: contact_a_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 108

Notice: Undefined index: contact_a_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 110

Notice: Undefined index: contact_b_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 112

Notice: Undefined index: contact_b_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 114

Notice: Undefined index: contact_b_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 117

Notice: Undefined index: contact_b_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 118

Notice: Undefined index: contact_a_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 130

Notice: Undefined index: contact_b_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 137

Notice: Undefined index: contact_a_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: contact_b_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 152

Notice: Undefined index: contact_a_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 160

Notice: Undefined index: contact_b_civicrm_contact in /home/cooldavis/www/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/RelationshipExtended.php on line 167

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: syntax error
Return to home page.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more complete. You haven't told us what version of civicrm you are using, whether you recently upgraded, whether it was working before, when it stopped working, whether you recently installed any extensions, moved to a different server, etc. Help us help you.

Comment: The long list of errors you have pasted are not the main error - which is not showing - if you can turn on debugging (civicrm/admin/setting/debug?reset=1) & try again you will get the DB error - which is likely to shed light

Comment: Regarding the civi version, etc.:  I'm sorry, my first version of the question had that information,   civi 4.4.14, WordPress.